# « Je n'avais pas le temps » ou « Je n'ai pas eu le temps » ?

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait

Quelle est la différence entre :

> Je n'avais pas le temps.

et

> Je n'ai pas eu le temps.

Dans quelles occasions utilisez-vous chaque phrase ?

Answer (score 5):

Comme le dit @chilladx, l'imparfait fait normalement référence à une situation qui a duré dans le temps alors que le passé composé dénote souvent quelque chose de plus ponctuel. Néanmoins, ce raisonnement n'est pas suffisant ici. « Je n'avais pas le temps » peut s'utiliser pour des événements extrêmement brefs, alors que « Je n'ai pas eu le temps » peut faire référence à une période assez longue. Ce qui les distingue, c'est que la forme à l'imparfait fait une référence au **moment auquel on a choisi de ne pas faire l'action** (ou auquel on a constaté son impossibilité), alors que la forme au passé composé constitue **un bilan portant sur une période révolue**.

> Je n'avais pas le temps d'éviter le piéton.

C'est un événement dramatiquement bref, mais qui peut néanmoins s'exprimer à l'imparfait. La phrase nous parle du moment de la réaction du conducteur, nous plaçant quasiment derrière le volant. Si l'on avait dit "je n'ai pas eu le temps d'éviter le piéton", on aurait évoqué un état de fait ancré dans le passé, révolu, sur lequel on ne peut revenir.

> Je n'ai pas eu le temps de rendre mon rapport dans les temps.

Il s'agit d'un constat après une échéance, et le passé composé est utilisé même si la période laissée pour la rédaction du rapport était de plusieurs mois. En écrivant au contraire "je n'avais pas le temps de rendre mon rapport à temps", on projette le lecteur dans cette période de rédaction, le mettant devant la contrainte de cette échéance trop courte.

Comment: "Je n'ai pas eu le temps de rendre mon rapport *à la date prévue*" serait préférable si l'on veut insister sur un bilan qui se fait après la fin d'un exercice.

Comment: Bien expliqué, mais, est-ce que cette une exception dans ce cas ? Parce qu’il me parait que c’est la contraire de la définition officiel du passé composé et l'imparfait.

Answer (score 0):

« Je n'avais pas le temps » représente une situation qui a duré, ou qui s'est répétée, dans le passé.

« Je n'ai pas eu le temps » est une action ponctuelle dans le passé.

En fait, c'est la différence entre l'imparfait de l'indicatif et le passé composé de l'indicatif.

Comment: Non, c'est une mauvaise explication que j'ai entendue bien trop souvent. Voir la réponse de Eusebius.